Android kernel module disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
I'm following the Linux Device Driver section of this PDF but am using android14-6.6-kernel as 6.1 fails to build on my machine.
I've extracted the driver source code from here, and placed the vendor folder into the root of the kernel build environment. It is a simple Linux driver circular-driver/circular-char.c and a BUILD.bazel.
After building with tools/bazel run //vendor:vendor_x86_64_dist, I've installed the .ko both by placing it in kernel/prebuilts/common-modules/virtual-device/6.6/x86-64/circular-char.ko in the AOSP source code and by pointing the Cuttlefish virtual device to the whole compiled kernel with:
export DIST_FOLDER=/aosp/kernel/common-android15-6.6-kernel/out/virtual_device_x86_64/dist
launch_cvd -console=true --noresume -initramfs_path "${DIST_FOLDER}"/initramfs.img -kernel_path "${DIST_FOLDER}"/bzImage

However, it fails to load:
modprobe: Failed to load module circular_char: Exec format error
circular_char: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout

I've seen that this can be caused by compiling it against a different kernel version, but I don't see anything that isn't kernel-version-agnostic in the driver source / build setup, and I've booted Cuttlefish with the entire compiled kernel (not just adding the single .ko).
